# How come this program gives no errors when I run it, but it also gives no results?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
   
int main(void) {
    char inputMonth[50];
    int inputDay;

    scanf("%s", inputMonth); 
    scanf("%d", &inputDay);

    if (strcmp(inputMonth,"March" )==0) && (inputDay >= 20 && inputDay <= 30) || (strcmp (inputMonth,"June")==0) && (inputDay >=20 && inputDay <=30))
        printf("Spring");
     
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I try to execute it says "error: expected identifier before‘(’ token". which is on line 10

Comment: What input are you providing?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't compiled your program. Your if statement doesn't appear to have enough brackets. It all should be inside of a ()

Comment: The problem is that the input is provided is " March 30" not " March ENTER 30"

Comment: How can you run it if it does not compile?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Last time I checked, March had 31 days...

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Your code was missing a `(` here is the fixed version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char inputMonth[50];
   int inputDay;




    scanf("%s", inputMonth); 
    scanf("%d", &inputDay);


    if ((strcmp(inputMonth,"March" ) == 0) && 
       (inputDay >= 20 && inputDay <= 30) || 
       (strcmp (inputMonth,"June") == 0) && 
       (inputDay >= 20 && inputDay <= 30)) {
        printf("Spring");
    }
 

 return 0;
}
```

These lines of code

```
scanf("%s", inputMonth); 
scanf("%d", &inputDay);
```

Are expecting you to provide input through the terminal. Try typing into your terminal (hit enter after March then hit enter after 30)

```
March
30
```

After you start running the program and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, see now the code goes thru with no erros its just not producing any output when I try and execute it.

Comment: Did you try typing `March` into your command line/terminal and pressing enter, and then typing `30` into your command line and pressing enter?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the input that is being provided is "March 30" and not  "March enter 30"

Comment: @Hydropull: The posted solution works with me both with `"March 30"` and with `"March\n30"`. In both cases, it prints `"Spring"`. Please state the exact input that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Yeah I got it now thanks